# Oracle Json function did not return the result I expected

Tags: json, oracle, oracle19c

I have a table with oracle json column, and use json sql query function JSON_TEXTCONTAINS like below, I use multiple JSON_TEXTCONTAINS and join with or/and operator:

```sql
select json_value(json_value, '$.customerIdCode'),
 json_value(json_value, '$.TYPE')
 FROM addcols_json addjson
  WHERE (JSON_TEXTCONTAINS (addjson.json_value,'$.TYPE','ZHS')
    or JSON_TEXTCONTAINS (addjson.json_value,'$.TYPE','ABC'))
       and (JSON_TEXTCONTAINS(    addjson.json_value, '$."customerIdCode"' ,'967')
           or JSON_TEXTCONTAINS(    addjson.json_value, '$."customerIdCode"' ,'351'));
```

expect query result like below:

```
customerIdCode  TYPE
967             ZHS,XXX
351             XXX,ABC
```

But I got this:

```
customerIdCode  TYPE
967             ZHS,XXX
351             XXX,ABC
123             ZHS,XXX
```

what I didn't expected is below record with customerIdCode(123) matched, seems
the oerpator and not work in my query.

```
customerIdCode  TYPE
123             ZHS,XXX
```

anyone know why and can give me some advise ?

thanks.

just edit my question and hope can express more clear.

Comment: the results are related with your data. So, need to share some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of `ZSH`:

```
967 ZHS,XXX        --> you have ZHS here (for 967)
351 XXX,ABC
123 ZHS,XXX        --> but, you have ZHS here as well (for 123)
```

As query says

```
WHERE (JSON_TEXTCONTAINS (addjson.json_value,'$.TYPE','ZHS')
                                                       ^^^
                                                       here
```

you got ... well, what you got.

Comment: sorry that I didn't express my requirement clear, 967, 351, 123 means  $."customerIdCode",  its not a part of $.TYPE, what my query is $."customerIdCode" match 967 or 351, but not 123, so this record 123,  ZHS,XXX should not return